# Label Preprocessing in Keras CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of 600 rows and 271 columns (last column contains class). Each row contains malware features and its class label. I am writing a code of Convolutional Neural Network to predict these classes. There are total 9 classes. Below is my code:

```
 dataset = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
 X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:270].values
 y = dataset.iloc[:, 270].values
 from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20)
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(Convolution1D(64, 10, input_shape=(643,270)))
 model.add(Activation('relu'))
 model.add(MaxPooling1D(1))
 model.add(Flatten())
 model.add(Dense(100))
 model.add(Dropout(0.5))
 model.add(Dense(9))
 model.add(Activation('softmax'))
 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
 X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (1, X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1]))
 X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (1, X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1]))
 y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10) 
 y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)
 model.fit(X_train,y_train,validation_data=(X_test,y_test))
 print(str(model.evaluate(x_test,y_test)))
```

Here i am getting an error on this line:

```
 model.fit(X_train,y_train,validation_data=(X_test,y_test))
 Error: Error when checking target: expected activation_2 to have shape (None, 9) 
 but got array with shape (643, 10)
```

because of "y_train" which is not in proper shape for training. Can someone explain me how to solve this problem and reshape y_train for successful training?

**EDIT:**
After changing the `input_shape` to second and third dimension shape, the error is now change to:

```
 fValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_2 to have shape (None, 1) 
 but got array with shape (643, 10)
```

Please any solution for this problem? 
Thanks!

Comment: Appertly you have 10 classes. And changing the last layer to ten outputs will solve this error. Also 600 datapoints divided by 10 classes nets you 60 data points per class. You really have too small a data set for deep learning. You should consider a simpler model

Comment: Actually i have a dataset of 11K datapoints. This is just for development phase. After changing it to 10, i am facing another weird error of inconsistent number of samples. After reshaping it to 3 dimension. The length of data is now 1 but code requires it in 3 dimension so what step should be taken here?

Comment: You `input_shape` is Wrong. You don’t enter number of data points here. Just the second and third dimensions shape. Please add the new error to the question.

Comment: @DJK the question is update. Please take a look at it.

Comment: I feel like there is still some missing information here I need to give you an answer. How has your model changed? did you change the last dense layer to 1 instead of ten?